# laravel 5.4 my query is returning empty collection

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i want sort my all artists in my artists table by alphabetical order, so i made alphabetical navigation menu. and route

```
Route::get('/artists/{letter}', 'mainController@showArtist')->where('letter', '[a-z]+')->name('list');
```

and this is showArtist method in my maincontroller.

```
public function showArtist($letter){
        $artists = Artist::where('name','like'.$letter.'%')->get();
        return view('front.list', compact('artists'));
```

this is returning empty collection array. if i dd($artists);

if var_dump($artists). it is show like this .

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#266 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`$artists = Artist::where('name','LIKE', $letter.'%')->get();`

Also, remember LIKE is case-sensitive.